# Toggle Button sharedpreferences Media Player

Tags: android

I have 2 activity. In first activity I have a toggle button(setChecked = true) and a Media Player. When toggle is on, Media Player start; when toggle is off, media Player pause and seekTo "0". There is no problem in there but I want to save toggle button situation. Because when user change toggle off and start second activity then turn back first activity toggle will change true again and Media Player start again. But user changed toggle as off and s/he don't want to listen my media...

My global variables(in first activity);

```
MediaPlayer main;
ToggleButton seskontrol;
```

My toggle button(in first activity);

```
    ToggleButton seskontrol = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.seskontrol);
    seskontrol.setChecked(true);
    seskontrol.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
            if (on) {
                // ON durumunda yapılacaklar
                main.start();
                main.setLooping(true);
            } else {
                // OFF durumunda yapılacaklar
                main.pause();
                main.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

On Create(in first activity);

```
    main.start();
    main.setLooping(true);
```

I know there is main.start(); in on create but how can I change it

```
if(toggle = on){
main.start();
}else{
main.pause();
main.seekTo(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this either by:
(1) Passing state of toggle variable in intent extras parameters between your activities.

To pass a toggle value between Activites:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("toggle", true);
```

And in the Activity class

```
boolean toggle = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("toggle");
```

or

(2) Using Shared Preference to store the state of toggle variable.

Setting values in Preference:

```
// MY_PREFS_NAME - a static String variable like: 
//public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();   
 editor.putBoolean("toggle", true);   
 editor.commit();
```

Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);   
Boolean toggle = prefs.getBoolean("toggle", true);   
if (toggle) {   
    // Your Code if toggle is true.   
}   
else   
{   
 // Your Code if toggle is false.   
}
```

Change the state of your toggle variable on change of toggle button state, and use that in your activity.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to String and toggle cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Which approach you are following and where you are getting this error.

Comment: Boolean toggle = prefs.getBoolean("toggle", true);

Comment: Make above change in line no. 26.

Comment: Have you changed String 'restoredText' to 'toggle'

Comment: Thanks so much! You Best!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109328/discussion-between-eren-and-rohit-sharma).